# How to mount an Android 4.4.4 in USB mass storage device mode?

Tags: usb, mount, android, data-recovery

I'm trying to mount Android phone (Lenovo P70-A) to recover deleted files. Phone is detected in `lsusb` and `dmesg`. Last command prints

```
usb-storage 1-3:1-0: USB mass storage device detected
    ...
sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

`/dev/sdb` has appeared, however the device isn't shown in `lsblk`.

Just `mount` returned error:

```
> sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/lenovo
> mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb
```

I managed to mount it with specific filesystem types (`mount ... ... -t <fs-type>`) as `bpf`, `cgroup2`, `cpuset`, `devpts`, `devtmpfs`, `fuse`, `fusectl`, `hugetlbfs`, `mqueue`, `pstore`, `proc`, `securityfs`, `sysfs`, `tmpfs` but they contain system files or just nothing. Btw device still wasn't in 'lsblk'. Such types as `ext2`, `ext3`, `ext4` and `vfat` gave the same errmsg "no medium...".

My aim is to recover deleted photos and videos so what should I do?

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Have you tried with `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`? It could easily be that there are multiple partitions (i.e. `sdb1`, `sdb2` and so on).

Comment: @MrShunz, thanks. It said "unable to open /dev/sdb: media is not found". Strange, but this file is still exist and info from post is relevant.

Comment: That's not going to work. You need to run dd from the phone over ADB and dump the partitions (the phone must be rooted).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, you're right, thanks, it helped

Comment: @Joeyjoey great! Could you please write a self answer detailing what you did?